# How to set date.timezone in php

Tags: apache-http-server, php

Hi guys i need to set date.timezone for a script i am using i have already tried php.ini file in /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
;date.timezone = Europe/Berlin

; http://php.net/date.default-latitude
;date.default_latitude = 31.7667

; http://php.net/date.default-longitude
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333

; http://php.net/date.sunrise-zenith
;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333

; http://php.net/date.sunset-zenith
```

output on phpinfo page

```
     Directive  Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   no value    no value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolon `;`, it makes the line a comment.